# .htaccess: HTTP to HTTPS redirecting not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect:
1) http://example.com to https://www.example.com
2) http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com

But my .htaccess usually ignores %{HTTPS} in RewriteCond...
Hence I am not able to handle the second mentioned case, it gives me cyclic redirection error message.

.htaccess is as follows:

```
# Redirect non-www urls to www
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example\.com/?$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com [NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com/?$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com [NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com\?.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [NC,R=301]
```

I will try to say very nice thank you! to anybody who will help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You really only need one rule for what you want.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Getting cyclic redirection :(

Comment: Clear your browser cache or try in another browser. That rule works.